# How can I use wget to save JavaServer HTML pages?

Tags: jsp, web-scraping, wget

http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/inquirySearchParam.jis

I'm trying to write a script to scrape dockets on the Maryland case search site, which has dockets of court cases for public record. It's for research and my goal is to eventually have a free site to more easily search cases based on charges, results, etc. Having some trouble though.

When users first reach the site, they have to accept a disclaimer before they can access any dockets. They will be redirected to the disclaimer if they try to access a docket via a direct link.

Try to access this direct link from a new session and you'll see what I mean.

http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/inquiryDetail.jis?caseId=C02CV19000081&loc=60&detailLoc=ODYCIVIL

If I just wget the links directly, I will end up saving just the disclaimer. I have tried accepting the disclaimer in my browser, then saving the cookie and using it in wget, but that doesn't work either. Still just redirects and saves the disclaimer as a jsp

Answer (score 0):

This took some testing with the server to identify what was needed.  The server actually requires that you send a specific POST request in order to get the record.

For the link you provided, the needed Wget command would be:

```
wget --method=POST --body-data="locationCode=DC&caseId=C02CV19000081&action=Get+Case"  --page-requisites 'http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/inquiryByCaseNum.jis;jsessionid=<Sess-ID>'
```

Simple breakdown:

- `--method=POST`: Send a HTTP POST Request
- `--body-data="..."`: This is the POST request body. The 3 parameters are obvious
- `--page-requisites`: Download any additional pages needed. In this case, it will download the right CSS files
- `URL`: This is the URL to the page. If you look closely, it is the URL to the search page along with an extra segment. This is the Session ID. To get this, accept the disclaimer in Firefox and then save the cookie. The value of the cookie is the session id. Add it to the URL.